# Get the changes made in a specific file at a specific commit?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I know you can do git log --stat and the do a git diff (commit1) (commit2), however, this gives me the changes in all of the files. I would like to see the changes in only a specific file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `$ git diff commit1 commit2 file-in-question`